# Can anybody give the some hints on "manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `emp` AS t LIMIT 1" in sqoop?

Tags: sqoop

In some sqoop programs, during execution we are receiving limit1 statement.
What is it? And why is MR generating this?

> manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `emp` AS t LIMIT 1" in sqoop?

Comment: Thank you Misa Lazovic to correct my sentence in a good manner.

Answer (score 0):

sqoop-import --connect  $ConnectionString --query "select * from table_name='TableName' where $CONDITIONS " --target-dir "/location/" -fields-terminated-by '\001' you can use sed or awk commands at the end of sqoop import to  print it to a file.
you can even use limit inside the query if you want.

Hope this answers your question.